# Как вызвать функцию с аргументами из потока?

Tags: c#, .net

Я создаю поток. В потоке вызываю функцию. В этой функции пишу код программы, попутно вызывая другие функции.

```
//При загрузке формы - создаём поток и в потоке выполняем "главную функцию".
private void RadForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Thread Main_thread = new Thread(main_function);
Main_thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
Main_thread.Start();
}

//А вот тут ошибки
public void main_function()
{
//Функция показа формы из потока. Код ниже с ошибками - VS подчеркивает красным и не компилирует.
this.Invoke(new Action(delegate {show_message_form("Идет загрузка.", 1)}); //Это не компилирует

//Функция скрытия формы из потока. Код без ошибок.
this.Invoke(new Action(hide_message_form));              
}




//Далее код других функций (можно не смотреть)
//Показ формы с сообщением
public void show_message_form(string form_text, int show_progress_image)
{

RadForm3 RadForm3 = new RadForm3();
RadForm3.Show();
RadForm3.radLabel2.Text=form_text;
if (show_progress_image == 1) RadForm3.pictureBox1.Visible = true;
this.Hide();
    }

//Скрытие формы с сообщением
public void hide_message_form()
{
this.Show();
RadForm3 RadForm3 = new RadForm3();
RadForm3.Hide();   
}
```

Как вызвать функцию (`show_message_form("Идет загрузка.", 1)`) с аргументами из потока?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке, с которым "не компилирует" конечно же не надо приводить, да?

Comment: ну и определение функции `show_message_from` и `hide_message_from` тоже хотелось бы видеть

Comment: Владимир - Сообщение об ошибке, с которым "не компилирует" не привёл т.к. "Код ниже с ошибками - VS подчеркивает красным" - написан экспромтом/наугад. Я не знал что писать, написал что более похоже на правду.

Comment: Код об ошибке, возможно, ничем не поможет. Но если вы хотите...
   this.Invoke(new Action(delegate {show_message_form("Идет загрузка (обновление) справочников. Пожалуйста, подождите.", 1)}));

Ошибка 1 Требуется ";" (после закрывающей скобки })
Ошибка 2 ожидалась ) (следом за закрывающей скобкой })
и т.д.
Это синтаксические ошибки. Я не знал что писать.


Алексей код функций добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените строчку с ошибкой на эту:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(()=>{ show_message_form("Идет загрузка.", 1); } ));
```

Comment: Работает. Но форма RadForm3 (//Скрытие формы с сообщением) не скрылась. Странно. Но главное, что ваш код работает.

Comment: Вы в коде метода  hide_message_form() создаёте новую форму (RadForm3 RadForm3 = new RadForm3();) и скрываете её (RadForm3.Hide(); ) а чтобы скрыть форму созданную в  show_message_form вам нужно обратиться именно к ней.